# Mac subprocess run with full path doesn't work

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

when I run the followin command in terminal it works, and starts application.

```
/Users/Someone/Documents/SomeApp\ v2.app/Contents/MacOS/SomeApp
```

But when I do the following in python, then run it:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['/Users/Someone/Documents/SomeApp\ v2.app/Contents/MacOS/SomeApp'])
```

I get the following error msg.:

```
File not found error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/Users/Someone/Documents/SomeApp\\ v2.app/Contents/MacOS/SomeApp'
```

Comment: Try removing the backslash in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't need the `'\'` in the string.